# Not able to show the logout button immediately after the user login in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working in my Ionic 4 app and I have made the login/register system.

When the user login, after that the user will able to visit the page and when the user is not login and try to visit the page, it will get redirect to the login page.

This is my **userlogin.page.ts**:

```
async UserLoginDetails($soctype, $socid) {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Please Wait',
      duration: 1100,
      translucent: true,
    });
    await loading.present();
    const userdetailslogin = {
      email: this.userlogindet.value.email,
      password: this.userlogindet.value.password,
      social_type: $soctype,
      social_id: $socid,
    };
    this.chakapi.loginUser(userdetailslogin, 'userLogin').subscribe((data) => {
      // console.log(data);
      if (data) {
        this.responseEdit = data;
        if (this.responseEdit.status === 'success') {
          // console.log(this.responseEdit.data.id);
          this.storage.set('ID', this.responseEdit.data.id);
          this.presentAlertConfirm('Login Successful', 1);
        } else {
          this.presentAlertConfirm('Either You are not registered Or not approved user.', 0);
        }
      }
    });
    return await loading.onDidDismiss();
}

async presentAlertConfirm($messge, $para) {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      message: $messge,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: () => {
            // console.log('Confirm Cancel: blah');
            if ($para === 1) {
              this.modalController.dismiss();
              this.router.navigate(['/tabs/tab2']);
            }
          }
        }]
    });
    await alert.present();
}
```

In this ts, after the successful login, I am storing the user id and the user will get redirect to the tab2 page.

And when the user is not login and try to visit the tab2 page, it will redirect to the register page.

This is my **app.component.html**:

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="myheader">
      <ion-title color="myheadtitle" slot="end" *ngIf="menuclick">Register/Login</ion-title>
      <ion-title color="myheadtitle" slot="end" (click)="logoutClicked()" *ngIf="menuclick2">Logout</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

This is my **app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { PopoverController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { PopoverPage } from './popover/popover.page';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  menuclick = true;
  menuclick2 = false;
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    public popoverController: PopoverController,
    public alertController: AlertController,
    private storage: Storage,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();

    this.storage.get('ID').then((val) => {
      if (val) {
        this.menuclick2 = true;
        this.menuclick = false;
      }
    });
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }


  logoutClicked() {
    this.storage.remove('ID').then(() => {
      this.menuclick2 = false;
      this.menuclick = true;
      this.router.navigate(['/tabs/tab1']);
    });
  }
}
```

In this ts file, I have the logic for the login and logout button.

But the problem is that, I am not able to shoe the logout button immediately after the user login.

This is my **tabs.router.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';
import { AuthenticationGuard } from '../guards/authentication.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab2/tab2.module#Tab2PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab4',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../login/login.module#LoginPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab3/tab3.module#Tab3PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

Please anyone suggest that, It is the good way or not for showing the login and logout button.

The problem is that, I am not able to show the logout button immediately after the user login.

I know that for this I have to create a service. So, Can anyone help me with the code.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not in Ionic framework but the problem is probably lying in the way you are getting `ID` from the storage in `app.component.ts`. ID is resolved in app component constructor and no updated after (the login for example). Consider creating subject in which you will store whether the user is logged in or not. It can look similar to `MessagesService` in this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xe52wh

Comment: @Bardr. What is the solution for that? Can you please help me with the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a user service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  private isLoggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  public isLoggedIn$ = this.isLoggedIn.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  public logIn() {
    this.isLoggedIn.next(true);
  }

  public logOut() {
    this.isLoggedIn.next(false);
  }
}
```

After user login in login page emit a new value for `UserService#isLoggedIn` using method `UserService#logIn`. Subscribe to observable `UserService#isLoggedIn$` in app component, and refresh the view based on observable using [`async` pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).

**EDIT:** Template for showing Logout button when user is logged in based on `UserService#isLoggedIn$`.

```
<ion-toolbar color="myheader">
  <ion-title color="myheadtitle" slot="end" *ngIf="menuclick">Register/Login</ion-title>
  <ion-title color="myheadtitle" slot="end" (click)="logoutClicked()" *ngIf="userService.isLoggedIn$ | async">Logout</ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
```

Comment: Thank you for the service. Can you also code for the buttons?  <ion-title color="myheadtitle" slot="end" *ngIf="menuclick">Register/Login</ion-title>
      <ion-title color="myheadtitle" slot="end" (click)="logoutClicked()" *ngIf="menuclick2">Logout</ion-title

Comment: Introducing an observable based service seems a bit excessive to control a single boolean.

Comment: @JayOrdway Probably in real world application you have more user related responsibilites that you can use `UserService` for. This is only an example for this question's purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to keep the header at the page level, so remove this from app.component.html, and put it in your user.login.html. In general, maintain the header and the login/logout buttons at the page level, if you do keep them in app.component and logic in app.component.ts you may need a service or to use events

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="myheader">
      <ion-title color="myheadtitle" slot="end" *ngIf="menuclick">Register/Login</ion-title>
      <ion-title color="myheadtitle" slot="end" (click)="logoutClicked()" *ngIf="menuclick2">Logout</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, show logout button grayed while you getting data from storage. It would be absolutely comfortable and predictable for UX.

Comment: something like this:`<ion-title color="myheadtitle" slot="end" (click)="logoutClicked()" [ngClass]="{'disabled': !isLoaded}" *ngIf="menuclick2">Logout</ion-title>` with appropriate part in module: `this.storage.get('ID').then((val) => { this.isLoaded = true;
      if (val) {
        this.menuclick2 = true;
        this.menuclick = false;
      }
    });`