# My Ionic App is continuously loading after setting the storage in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working in my Ionic 4 app and I am setting the User ID in the storage for showing the login and logout button.

This is my **userlogin.page.ts**:

```
this.chakapi.loginUser(userdetailslogin, 'userLogin').subscribe((data) => {
    if (data) {
        this.responseEdit = data;
        if (this.responseEdit.status === 'success') {
          this.storage.set('ID', this.responseEdit.data.id);
          this.chakapi.setUserID(this.responseEdit.data.id);
          this.presentAlertConfirm('Login Successful', 1);
        } else {
          this.presentAlertConfirm('Either You are not registered Or not approved user.', 0);
        }
    }
});
```

In this ts file, I am setting the storage.

This is **app.component.html**:

```
<ion-title color="myheadtitle" *ngIf="!chakapi.isLoggednIn()" slot="end">Register/Login</ion-title>
<ion-title color="myheadtitle" *ngIf="chakapi.isLoggednIn()" slot="end" (click)="logoutClicked()">Logout</ion-title>
```

In this html, I have two buttons, for login and for logout.

This is my **Service: chakapiservice**:

```
setUserID($token) {
  this.storage.set('ID', $token);
}
getUserID() {
  return this.storage.get('ID');
}
isLoggednIn() {
  return this.getUserID() !== null;
}
```

This is my **app.component.ts**:

```
logoutClicked() {
 this.storage.remove('ID').then(() => {
  this.menuclick2 = false;
  this.menuclick = true;
  this.router.navigate(['/tabs/tab1']);
 });
}
```

I don't know why after applying this code, my app keep loading. May be because of `return this.storage.get('ID');`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: First, did you check if there is no errors in console? Also provide a demo or something which we can investigate.

Comment: @Bardr. Yes, I have checked and there is not errors in the console.

Comment: @Bardr. The problem is in getUserID() because when I comment it, My app works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your template:

```
<ion-title color="myheadtitle" *ngIf="!chakapi.getUserID() | async" slot="end">Register/Login</ion-title>
<ion-title color="myheadtitle" *ngIf="chakapi.getUserID() | async" slot="end" (click)="logoutClicked()">Logout</ion-title>
```

If `this.storage.get('ID');` returns `Promise` this should work. And you don't have to check whether returned value is `null` or not because `null` is `false` actually.

**EDIT**: Also why are you setting the `ID` twice?

```
this.storage.set('ID', this.responseEdit.data.id);
this.chakapi.setUserID(this.responseEdit.data.id);
```

You can get rid of one of them.

**EDIT2**: Ultimately you can extend your `chakapiservice` to use subject for storing whether user is logged in or not:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChakApiService {
  // Add behavior subject.
  private isLoggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.getCredentials() !== null);
  public isLoggedIn$ = this.isLoggedIn.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  setUserID($token) {
    this.storage.set('ID', $token);
    localStorage.setItem('token', $token);
    this.isLoggedIn.next(true);
  }

  getCredentials(): string {
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
  }

  // Rest of the code omitted for brevity.
}
```

And then use it in `app.component.html`:

```
<ion-title color="myheadtitle" *ngIf="!chakapi.isLoggedIn$ | async" slot="end">Register/Login</ion-title>
<ion-title color="myheadtitle" *ngIf="chakapi.isLoggedIn$ | async" slot="end" (click)="logoutClicked()">Logout</ion-title>
```

Also you should add `localStorage.clear()` to your `logoutClicked()` method to remove `token` from `localStorage`.

Comment: Should I have to use observable with this?

Comment: Please provide a demo. Also I gave you a example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54979003/not-able-to-show-the-logout-button-immediately-after-the-user-login-in-ionic-4/54980894#54980894 And please accept an answer before opening a new question about the same issue. For now I'm leaving this answer for editing after you provide more info/demo.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Tomorrow I will check this code.

Comment: This is working but after logout, the login/register button is not showing and after login the logout button is showing but when i refresh the logout button is gone. Can you please help me?

Comment: @Rahul For `Register/Login` button I just copied your logic. I thought you want this behavior. After refresh the button is gone because in my snippet I'm not storing whether user is logged in or not in persistent storage. I can't help you with Ionic storage unless you provide demo but I can help you implementing this behavior using, for example,`local storage` if you want.

Answer (score 1):

`Storage.get` is async try this

```
this.storage.get('ID').then((val) => {
   return val !== null ? true : false
  });
```

and

```
isLoggednIn() { 
return this.getUserID();
 }
```

Rest of the code looks fine for me :)
make sure you have done all the settings as describe here : https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage

Comment: But I want to return this value as to check in isLoggednIn().

Comment: check the latest code you can do something like this

Comment: isLoggednIn() {
  return this.getUserID();
}

Comment: My app is still keep loading.

Comment: The problem is in getUserID() because when I comment it, My app works fine.